# Make Windows 7 hibernate C:\ partition only

Tags: windows, multi-boot, hibernate

I have 3 partitions:

```
/dev/sda:
  /dev/sda1   Windows 7 (C:\)
  /dev/sda2   Shared NTFS partition (D:\)
  /dev/sda6   Ubuntu 13.04
```

I will hibernate Windows 7 then boot to Ubuntu, it works fine, but any changes I make to the 'Shared NTFS partition' will not be seen by Windows.

Is there a way to make Windows only hibernate the state of the `C:` drive so that I can edit files in the 'Shared NTFS partition' and have them be seen by Windows?

Answer (score 3):

this is not possible. Windows doesn't close all handles and flushes the data to disk. This also causes [data loss in Windows 8 when you use the new faststartup feature](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html).

If you want to boot into Linux shutdown Windows correctly.

Comment: I can boot into and use Linux when Windows is hibernated, I just can't edit the D: partition. Isn't there a way I can unmount the D: partition before shutting down windows?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. Shutdown Windows correctly to avoid this issue.

Comment: Well, you could close all files on D:\, start disk management (start, run, `diskmgmt.msc`) and remove the drive letter or mount path for the D: volume or use cmd in combination with `mountvol`. That might work (might since I do not know how much more information windows will remember if you hibernate. So shutting down rather than hibernating ias the safe choice).